# [TypeGraphQL]Cannot determine GraphQL input type

Tags: reactjs, typegraphql

An error occurs in the following configuration. Please tell me the cause of the error and how to fix it.

#### ■Error message

> Error: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'zzzzzInputs' of 'XxxxxInput' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?

#### ■Reproduction environment and method

1. Clone
   `git clone https://github.com/isoittech/hellpj-type-graphql`
2. Execute commands
   `npm ci`
   `npm run start`

#### ■Application/library stack

- Node.js/Express
- sequelize
- sequelize-typescript
- type-graphql

#### ■Source

https://github.com/isoittech/hellpj-type-graphql/blob/master/src/main/graphql/ppppp.resolver.ts

```js
@ObjectType()
export class ZzzzzInput {
    @Field((type) => ZzzzzType)
    zzzzz!: ZzzzzType;
    // @Field()
    // zzzzz!: string;
}

@InputType()
export class XxxxxInput {
    @Field((type) => [ZzzzzInput])
    zzzzzInputs!: ZzzzzInput[];
    // @Field((type) => [String])
    // zzzzzInputs!: string[];
}

@Resolver((of) => Yyyyy)
export class XxxxxResolver {
    @Mutation((returns) => Yyyyy)
    async addXxxxx(@Arg("Xxxxx") XxxxxInput: XxxxxInput): Promise<Yyyyy> {
        const serviceOutput: XxxxxServiceOutputDto = {};

        return Promise.resolve(serviceOutput.addedXxxxx!);
    }
}
```

#### ■I coded it by referring to here.

https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html
[Cannot determine GraphQL input type for argument named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681836/cannot-determine-graphql-input-type-for-argument-named)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by modifying like below. Look at '★'.
(And found another one, solved too.)

#### ■Source

```js
// @ObjectType()   // ★  Before
@InputType()       // ★  After
export class ZzzzzInput {
    @Field((type) => ZzzzzType)
    zzzzz!: ZzzzzType;
    // @Field()
    // zzzzz!: string;
}

@InputType()
export class XxxxxInput {
    @Field((type) => [ZzzzzInput])
    zzzzzInputs!: ZzzzzInput[];
    // @Field((type) => [String])
    // zzzzzInputs!: string[];
}

@Resolver((of) => Yyyyy)
export class XxxxxResolver {
    @Mutation((returns) => Yyyyy)
    async addXxxxx(@Arg("Xxxxx") XxxxxInput: XxxxxInput): Promise<Yyyyy> {
        const serviceOutput: XxxxxServiceOutputDto = {};

        return Promise.resolve(serviceOutput.addedXxxxx!);
    }
}
```

#### ■Related source

node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js

```js
    static getGraphQLInputType(target, propertyName, type, typeOptions = {}, parameterIndex, argName) {
        let gqlType;
        gqlType = types_1.convertTypeIfScalar(type);
        if (!gqlType) {
            ★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★
            ★ Finding process below not worked when @ObjectType.
            ★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★★
            const inputType = this.inputTypesInfo.find(it => it.target === type);
            if (inputType) {
                gqlType = inputType.type;
            }
        }
        if (!gqlType) {
            ☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆
            ☆ Finding process below not worked when wrong order in src/index.ts.
            ☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆
            const enumType = this.enumTypesInfo.find(it => it.enumObj === type);
            if (enumType) {
                gqlType = enumType.type;
            }
        }
        if (!gqlType) {
            throw new errors_1.CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError("input", target.name, propertyName, parameterIndex, argName);
        }
        const { nullableByDefault } = build_context_1.BuildContext;
        return types_1.wrapWithTypeOptions(target, propertyName, gqlType, typeOptions, nullableByDefault);
    }
```

#### ■Another problem

After I've solved above problem, another one occured. Error message is below:

> Error: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'zzzzz' of 'ZzzzzInput' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?

Look at ☆ in schema-generator.js.
Enum type 'ZzzzzType' couldn't be found, so error occured.
Because `this.enumTypesInfo` doesn't contain 'ZzzzzType'.
Because I executed registering Enumtype after SchemaGenerating process.
I had to modify below.

```js
    // enable Enum
    registerEnumType(ZzzzzType, {
        name: "ZzzzzType",
    });
    const schema = await buildSchema({
        resolvers: [__dirname + "/graphql/*.resolver.ts"],
        emitSchemaFile: true,
        validate: false,
    });
//    // enable Enum
//    registerEnumType(ZzzzzType, {
//        name: "ZzzzzType",
//    });
```